# Convert jpg image to tif image format in java

Tags: java

I want to read a JPEG image and get the tiff byte[] or write it to a tiff file.

```
FileSeekableStream stream = new FileSeekableStream("C:\\Users\\chathurangarw\\Desktop\\download.tiff");
    TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();
    decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
    ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
    params.add(stream);
    RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
    BufferedImage img = image1.getAsBufferedImage();
    ImageIO.write(img, "TIFF", new File("C:\\Users\\chathurangarw\\Desktop\\asdf.tif"));
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Any exceptions or what means "It's not working"?

Comment: No exceptions, but image will not create. Now I think I found a solution.